# Difference of positive and negative integers while rounding

Tags: python, rounding

Why 
`13 // 3` gives `4` and
`-13 // 3` gives `-5`
if the distance to the nearest integer value is the same?

Answer (score 4):

Because the `//` operator is **floor** division, which means it rounds it **down** to the nearest whole number.

You can read a bit more about it [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/operators). Specifically:

> Floor division - division that results into whole number adjusted to the left in the number line

---

In your specific example:

`13 / 3` results in `4.333...` which will round down to `4`.

`-13 / 3` results in `-4.333...` which will round down to `-5`.

Answer (score 0):

`13//3=int of(4.3333)=4`, where 4 is the nearest smaller integer of `4.333....`.

`-13//3=int of(-4.333)=-5`, Where -5 is the nearest smaller integer of `-4.333...`,as we know that `-5` is smaller than `-4.333...`.